# MySQL How convert numeric variable to string inside Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

How can I convert a numeric variable to a string inside a Stored Procedure (not field of table)?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

`CAST(column AS VARCHAR(10))`  Or  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column)`